# Find maximum depth/level of a nested collection

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, tree

I want to create a Property which can find the depth of the nested tree structure. The below static finds out the depth/level by recursion. But is it possible to make this function as a property in the same class instead of a static method?

```
public static int GetDepth(MenuGroup contextMenuItems)
{
    if (contextMenuItems == null || contextMenuItems.Items.Count == 0)
        return 0;

    var subMenu = contextMenuItems.Items.Select(b => b as MenuGroup);
    if (!subMenu.Any())
        return 1;

    var subLevel = subMenu.Cast<MenuGroup>().Select(GetDepth);
    return !subLevel.Any() ? 1 : subLevel.Max() + 1;
}
```

Some more info on the code:
**MenuGroup** and **MenuItem** are derived from **MenuBase**

**MenuGroup** has children nodes with `ObservableCollection<MenuBase> Items` as Child Elements

**MenuItem** is a leave node without any child.

Comment: You can make property like this: `public int Depth {get {return GetDepth(something);} private set;}` something is that MenuGroup. You can make method private and non-static and use `this` in this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could easily turn it into an instance property, yes:

```
public int Depth
{
    get
    {
        if (Items.Count == 0)
            return 0;
        var subMenu = Items.Select(b => b as MenuGroup);
        if (!subMenu.Any())
            return 1;
        var subLevel = subMenu.Cast<MenuGroup>().Select(x = > x.Depth);
        return !subLevel.Any() ? 1 : subLevel.Max() + 1;
    }
}
```

That won't *quite* work yet due to the handling of non-`MenuGroup` items, but it can easily be fixed, using `OfType` instead of the `Select` and then `Cast`:

```
public int Depth
{
    get
    {
        // Completely empty menu (not even any straight items). 0 depth.
        if (Items.Count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // We've either got items (which would give us a depth of 1) or
        // items and groups, so find the maximum depth of any subgroups,
        // and add 1.
        return Items.OfType<MenuGroup>()
                    .Select(x => x.Depth)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty() // 0 if we have no subgroups
                    .Max() + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @defaultlocale: In fact it wasn't *quite* unnecessary. It took me a while to work out what was going on, but I think I've got it now. `OfType` is certainly cleaner though, I agree - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GenerateMenu()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<nav id=\"nvMenu\" class=\"main-nav\"><ul>");
    sb.Append(PrepareMenuUL(AppConfig._AppConfigInstance.Navigation.FirstOrDefault().NavigationClass));
    sb.Append("</ul></nav>");
    return sb.ToString();
}

private string PrepareMenuUL(List<Navigation> navigation)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (Liflag == 1)
    {
        sb.Append("</li>");
        Liflag = 0;
    }

    foreach (var item in navigation)
    {
        var subMenu = item.NavigationClass.Select(b => b as Navigation);

        if (subMenu.Any())
        {
            sb.Append("<li class=\"dropdown\">");
            if (subMenu.Any() && item.Url == "#")
                sb.Append(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}<i class=\"icon-arrow\"></i></a>", BaseUrl + item.Url, item.Name));
            else if (subMenu.Any() && item.Url != "#" && item.Url != null)
                sb.Append(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}<i class=\"icon-rightarrow\"></i></a>", BaseUrl + item.Url, item.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("<li>");
            sb.Append(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", BaseUrl + item.Url, item.Name));
        }

        if (subMenu.Any())
            sb.Append("<ul class=\"wd190\">");

        if (item.NavigationClass.Count > 0)
        {
            Liflag = 1;
            sb.Append(PrepareMenuUL(item.NavigationClass));
        }

        sb.Append("</li>");

        if (subMenu.Any())
            sb.Append("</ul>");
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You can user recursion to find the depth of list. in above showed manner